# Can I have a question? When we can use Pair of, bunch of, set of,?

Tags: grammar

So I can not speak english very well and some days ago in my english class we were talking about this words, like bunch of flowers, pair of pyjamas, set of traffics light. And I had all question wrong because I dont know difference betwen these words. Can someone explain me how you can use it?

Comment: Welcome! Please start by looking up the three words in a dictionary. I don't think that will answer all your questions, and might give you some new ones, but please use the "Edit" button to tell about what you found and what questions remain.

Comment: Also, did you ask your teacher to explain?

Answer (score 3):

These are called **collective nouns** and there are a lot of them! Of the ones you mentioned, here are some rules:

### Pair

Pair means two. A pair of something means that there are two items/people/etc. and usually means that they are similar or in some way go together. Examples:

- I have a **pair** of dogs, they are both cute dalmatians.
- You should go to the store and buy a **pair** of shoes.
- Her history class required her to buy a **pair** of textbooks. (Means that she needed to buy exactly two books.)

We also use the word **pair** to talk about pants, underpants/underwear, pajamas, glasses, and a few other types of clothing, even though these are actually just one item. So you might say "I need to buy another pair of pants." which actually means buying one piece of clothing, not two.

### Set

A **set** is a group of things that go together or were made together. Usually it means more than two, but could be any number larger than that. Here are some examples:

- This is my favorite **set** of pens. I like that they have a case to carry all the different colors in.
- I bought a **set** of comic books at the bookstore. Look at the art, it's so cool!
- He has a new cooking **set**. It has 3 pans and 2 pots in it.

### Bunch

A **bunch** is a loosely or informally held group. The description of "loosely held" might be physical or might be theoretical. Typically these items don't automatically go together or they aren't curated in the same way as a set. There might be repeat items where some but not all are exactly the same. The word **bunch** has a connotation of being a little sloppy or careless. A **bunch** also usually means "a lot" or "many" or "more than expected."

- I reached into the bucket and grabbed a **bunch** of candy in my hand.
- Here is a **bunch** of flowers I picked for you from the field.
- I have a whole **bunch** of t-shirts in my drawer.
- That family has a **bunch** of kids - I can't keep track of all of them!
- My teacher's lectures were not very organized. It's like she just had a **bunch** of ideas and no structure.

Most nouns can go with specific collective nouns but not other ones. It's okay if you don't know specifically which to use in which contexts right now. You'll learn them with time and you can always Google or ask here to find out more specifics.

Comment: Thank you very much...Im shy so I dont like to talk with other people face to face. And I will feel stupid to ask question in front of class where everyone know how to use these words. Thank you

Comment: @BTSARMY These words are confusing. I very much believe that your classmates will also not know how to use them yet either!

Comment: @BTSARMY Note, when "pair" is used for a single thing, it's usually because that thing has two parts. Like a pair of eyeglasses has two lenses or a pair of pants has two legs. It can be confusing because only certain words do this. If I say "buy me a pair of pants," I expect one piece of clothing. But for "buy me a pair of t-shirts" I expect two (even though a shirt has two sleeves!).

Comment: I guess grapes grow in *bunches* because their clusters have no fixed size.

Comment: @AntonSherwood That's true and a good thought! Another synonym for *bunch* could be *cluster," which also doesn't have a fixed size. We don't say "clusters of grapes" though, so it's somewhat arbitrary which word is "correct."

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon - We _can_ say [clusters of grapes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clusters+of+grapes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), though it isn't the usual expression in everyday life.